# Создание расширяемых таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, entity-framework

Подскажите, как можно рационально создать таблицу/ы для осуществления заполнения информации по составу объекта. Для пояснения вопроса можно рассмотреть множество ящиков с разным количеством ячеек - у каждой ячейки имеется номер позиции. По сути каждый ящик в EF - это сущность которая содержит поля типа: ID, Name, position,ID_object,quantity. ID_object - внешний ключ, сюда будет записываться ID определенного материала.
Скрин ниже показывает некий объект (ящик) содержащий всего 1 ячейку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но проблема в том что следующий может содержать уже 2,5...50 а может и более ячеек и по сути для данных позиции необходимо расширить таблицу (вправо!), добавив Position, ID_object, Quantity столько раз - сколько в ящике будет содержаться материала. Но что в этом случае делать для тех объектов у которых меньше ячеек - программно заполнять NULL значениями? Или есть более рациональный способ с добавлением новых сущностей которые поясняли бы отдельные моменты объекта?

Comment: В таблице оставляете только ID и Name. А поля position, id_object, Quantity выносите в другую таблицу добавив к записи еще и id и первой таблице. при необходимости "расширения в право" просто добавляете новые записи с тем же id и нужными остальными полями

Comment: Тоже думал в сторону создания новой таблицы, но неясно насколько вырастит прожорливость по отношению к занимаемому пространству на сервере. В C# есть понятие Jagged array, но как данную логику реализовать в SQL другой вопрос.

Comment: Забудьте про пространство. Хранить данные в реляционной БД как либо по другому нельзя. Как раз писать SQL запросы к данным расположенным по горизонтали станет очнь сложной задачей. SQL на это просто не рассчитан. Например как получить сумму всех Quantity ? `coalesce(q1,0)+coalsece(q2,0)+....` слишком сложные конструкции выходят. элементарный `select sum(q) from tab where id=X` несколько короче... А как найти все записи с определенным id_object ? `where id1=X or id2=X ...` опять же длинно и гарантированное сканирование всей таблицы, работа по индексам становится невозможной